# Using bash's "write" command to message a user from within a function call

Tags: messaging, bash

I am trying to write a function to insert into my .bash_profile that I can call to send a preset message to another user.  The idea would be something like:

```
function send_msg
{
    write username
    Hello!
    This is the preset message!
{
```

This, however, creates an unexpected EOF error when I try to reload the profile.  I tried experimenting with statements like "exit" to end the write (it usually is terminated with a ctrl+c), but I couldn't get that to work either.  Does anyone know if something like this is possible?  Thanks!

Comment: You have a `{` instead of a `}` at the end of your function. I'm putting this as a comment as I'm not sure if there's also a problem with the rest of the function.

Answer (score -1):

You can write a bash script that does what you want, place it to your ~/bin or /usr/bin (or elsewhere) and add an alias to this script in your .bash_profile

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question. The asker already knows where to put the function, they want to know what the bug is and how to fix it.